# Using QStandardItemModel like QStringListModel

Tags: qt, qt4

I am trying to use QStandardItemModel to do the same thing as QStringListModel (just for practice):

http://programmingexamples.net/wiki/Qt/ModelView/StandardItemModel

However, one cell shows up, but it is empty, as opposed to containing "text" as I would expect. Can anyone explain this? Is this the right way to go about using the QStandardItemModel (i.e. constructing QStandardItems and feeding them to the model?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually, I'm surprised you aren't getting a crash. You are creating `item0` on the stack, then passing a pointer to it to the `QList`. When that method leaves scope, `item0` is deleted, and your list contains a pointer to the rotting area of memory that *used* to hold a `QStandardItem`.

```
{
  QStandardItem item0("test");
  QList<QStandardItem*> items;
  items.insert(0, &item0);  // Doesn't transfer ownership
  model->appendRow (items);
}  // Out of scope! Oh no!
```

Typically you would just create the new item, then add it using something like `QStandardItemModel::setItem`, like this:

```
QStandardItem *item0 = new QStandardItem("test");
model->setItem(0, 0, item);  // transfers ownership of item0 to the model
```

Comment: Argh, I've done that a few times now - one of these days I will remember that! I keep attributing problems on my misuse of Qt instead of my misuse of normal c++ haha. Thanks.